# Iterate on all elements next to the selector javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have a select boxes with same class **super-attribute-select** in different elements like

```
<dd class="clearfix swatch-attr" style="display: none;">
    <div class="input-box">
        <select name="super_attribute[327]" id="attribute327" class="required-entry super-attribute-select no-display swatch-select"
            style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Choose an Option...</option><option value="2178" price="0" data-label="not specified" selected="selected">Not Specified</option></select>
    </div>
</dd>
<dd>
    <div class="input-box field__input-wrapper">
        <select name="super_attribute[481]" id="attribute481" class="required-entry super-attribute-select field__input field__input--select"
            style="pointer-events: none;">
    <option value="">Choose an Option...</option><option value="5531" price="0" data-label="intel core i5">Intel Core I5</option></select>
    </div>
</dd>
<dd>
    <div class="input-box field__input-wrapper">
        <select name="super_attribute[500]" id="attribute500" class="required-entry super-attribute-select field__input field__input--select"
            style="pointer-events: none;">
    <option value="">Choose an Option...</option><option value="5828" price="0" data-label="8 gb ddr3">8 GB DDR3</option></select>
    </div>
</dd>
<dd>
    <div class="input-box field__input-wrapper validation-passed">
        <select name="super_attribute[542]" id="attribute542" class="required-entry super-attribute-select field__input field__input--select validation-passed">
    <option value="">Choose an Option...</option><option value="9396" price="424" data-label="3.3 ghz">3.3 GHz</option><option value="9393" price="300" data-label="3.2 ghz">3.2 GHz -BHD 124.00</option><option value="9628" price="84" data-label="3.1 ghz">3.1 GHz -BHD 340.00</option><option value="9626" price="0" data-label="2.8 ghz">2.8 GHz -BHD 424.00</option></select>
    </div>
</dd>
<dd style="display: block;">
    <div class="input-box field__input-wrapper">
        <select name="super_attribute[543]" id="attribute543" class="required-entry super-attribute-select field__input field__input--select"
            style="pointer-events: none; display: block;">
    <option value="">Choose an Option...</option><option value="9857" price="0" data-label="amd radeon r9 290x">AMD Radeon R9 290X</option></select>
    </div>
</dd>
<dd class="last">
    <div class="input-box field__input-wrapper">
        <select name="super_attribute[629]" id="attribute629" class="required-entry super-attribute-select field__input field__input--select"
            style="pointer-events: none;" disabled="">
    <option value="">Choose an Option...</option><option value="13288" price="0" data-label="1 tb">1 TB</option></select>
    </div>
</dd>
```

I have js function that trigger on change select value

```
jQuery('.super-attribute-select').on('change', function () {jQuery('.super-attribute-select').each(function () {}}
```

i am using **.each** to iterate on these select boxes when any select value is change.

But i want to iterate only on those **select boxes** that came after this changed select not on all selects from start to end. Like if i changed **third select box** loop iteration must starts from third not from first.I have tried `.nextAll()` but it only iterate on siblings its not working in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu can do in this way

```
jQuery(this).closest('dd').nextAll('dd').find('.super-attribute-select');
```

Comment: so dd siblings are not ('.super-attribute-select') how can this work..?

Comment: I edit my answer. I get the first parent with with dd tag, than i get all next siblings with the same tag and I find in the result all elements that have the super-attribute-select class

Comment: Yes, you can use each to loop over elements

Comment: Thanks got it...:)